# Integrating Line Segment and Path

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Just wondering if anyone can give some assistance. I'm stuck on an exam question:

$\ \vec F (x,y,z) = (6xy + 4xz)\vec i + (3x^2 + 2yz)\vec j + (2x^2 + y^2)\vec k , x,y,z ∈\Bbb R.$

Evaluate
$$\ \int_Γ \vec F.\vec {dr} $$ where Γ is the path $\ y=x^2, z=0$ from (0,0,0) to (2,4,0) followed by the line seqment from (2,4,0) to (1,1,2).

My immediate thought was green's theorem but I don't think that would be possible. Previous parts to the question included checking if the function was conservative if that helps in any way.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What does complex integration have to do with this?

Comment: I guess it "complex" as in "difficult".

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $\text{curl}\, \vec F=0$, so $\vec F$ is conservative. Then you have 
$$
\int_\Gamma \vec F\cdot d\vec r=g(1,1,2)-g(0,0,0),
$$
where $g$ is a potential function for $\vec F$. One such function is $g(x,y,z)=3x^2y+y^2z+2x^2z$. Then 
$$
\int_\Gamma \vec F\cdot d\vec r=g(1,1,2)-g(0,0,0)=3+2+4=9.
$$

Comment: thank you for your reply! can I just ask, where did you get the function $g(x,y,z)=3x^2+y^2z+2x^2z$. from? Is that how I do the whole question or is there more to it?

Comment: Well, I just "saw" what it had to be. But knowing how to find the potential function is certainly a requirement to do this kind of problems. If I were marking this problem, an answer like mine, as it is written, would get about half the marks.

Comment: So if I write out the whole process of finding the potential would that get full marks or is there something else you have to do?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I don't think your $\;g\;$ is a potential of $\;F\;$. For example, the partial derivative with respect to $\;x\;$ isn't equal to the first entry of $\;F\;$ . I think it is lucky that function gives $\;9\;$ as result, as it is the same I got with what I think is an actual potential of $\;F\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo: it was simply a typo, there was a $y$ missing in the first term.

Comment: @blank: of course it depends on how you are taught and what the instructor's expectations are. In a question like this, you are supposed to recognize that $\vec F$ is conservative, find the potential function, and use it to calculate the integral, by noticing that in such situation you can just evaluate the potential function at the end points (this probably has a name, in your course, maybe Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? or something similar). Of course, it could happen that $\vec F$ is not conservative, and then you are probably expected to calculate the integral directly.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you, indeed so: just a typo . I thought you did the calculations in your mind, just like I began doing it. Yet I think the asker may not know the procedure, that's why I wrote it down.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer, curl$\,\vec F=0\;$ , so we can try to find its potential $\;U(x,y,z)\;$:

$$U_x=6xy+4xz\implies U=3x^2y+2x^2z+C(y,z)\;,\;\;C(y,z)\;\text{a constant in}\;x\implies$$

$$3x^2+2yz=U_y=3x^2+C_y(y,z)\implies C(y,z)=y^2z+K(z)=\text{ constant in y}\implies$$

$$2x^2+y^2=U_z=2x^2+y^2+K'(z)\implies K(z)=T=\text{ constant}\implies$$

$$U(x,y,z)=3x^2y+2x^2z+y^2z+T$$

and from here:

$$\int_\Gamma \vec F\cdot d\vec r=U(1,1,2)-U(0,0,0)=3+4+2=9$$